# How I can round and remove decimal places in SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, rounding

How can I remove my decimal places and round it to the nearest whole?
My formula is:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemNumber;

CStr(ItemNumber, "0") & "/" & CStr(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}))
```

I got my output below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were very close to having it correct.  You just had a small syntax error in your `CSTR()` function.  When converting numbers to text in a string you should use 2 arguments as `CSTR(x, y)`.  Where `x` is the number you want to convert to string text, and `y` is the number of decimal places to maintain.  There are 2 additional optional argument for this function, z and w, that can be used to specify the character used for the thousands separator and decimal point respectively.  Following this syntax, your formula should be:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemNumber;

CStr(ItemNumber, 0) & "/" & CStr(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.WorkOrderNo}),0)
```

So by removing the quotes around the `0` in your first `CSTR()` function and adding the `, 0` to your second `CSTR()` function, you should achieve the output desired.

Comment: Thanks for this but why is it printing the total number of lines in1 salesorder? So for example, I have 1 Workorder with 2 different lines, then the output should be 1/1 and 1/1,

Comment: please assist me. So for example, I have 1 Workorder with 2 different lines, then the output should be 1/1 and 1/1,

Comment: Trish - I would recommend starting a new question for this issue.  That will get more attention than a comment on this answered question, while also helping the site to stay more organized.  I will keep an eye out for your question and chime in if I think I can help, but I'm currently working on a large project myself and have to focus on my deadlines.